# What is the output for the following code segment in C?

Tags: c

When I run this in my compiler I get 0044, could someone please tell me if the output that I get is right?

And what this whole code segment mean?

```
   int main () {


   int X[10]={0};

    int N = 4;

    int k ;

    for(k = 0; k< N;k++){

     X[k] = k*2;

     printf("%d" , X[N/2]);

    }
}
```

Comment: You ask what the output is, but then say that the output is "0044". Then you ask if the output is right -- what do you mean by "right"? Right or wrong depends on what the program is supposed to do, but you don't say what that is. The tour (http://stackoverflow.com/tour) is worth a look on how to ask good questions and to ask them in a way that's acceptable here.

Comment: -1 This is not a very good question.  It essentially asks if your C compiler is properly operating.  Certainly that piece of code will type "0044" (without a newline, so your prompt will start right after that), but there is no information in the question about why you felt it was a useful thing to ask.

Answer (score 2):

Yes the answer is right.
in the step `int X[10]={0};` you have initialised all the array elements to zero.
`printf("%d" , X[N/2]);` Here you wanted to print `X[2]` which is `0` till `k=2`. After `k=2` its value is changed to `4`. And hence `0044`.

Comment: `Here you wanted to print X[2] ` ... i think it must instead be `Here you wanted to print X[N/2] ` in your answer

Comment: @CherubimAnand: but N is a constant so the answer is correct.